How to access raw media data using only MediaStreamTrack
I want to understand the Web API a bit better, specifically how the media recording works. I know I can record the media using the MediaRecorder, but that's a pretty high level.
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((mediaStream) => {
    // How do I tap into the actual data stream from the microphone?
    // Without using the MediaRecorder as illustrated bellow
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
    mediaRecorder.start();
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => { /*...*/ }
});

I thought I could tap into the mic data stream myself, but after exploring the MediaStreamTrack API, I don't see any indication of how to do this. It seems that MediaStreamTrack only contains metadata, not the actual data stream or any onDataAvailable event.
Here I found:

A single MediaStreamTrack can represent multi-channel content, such as stereo or 5.1 audio or stereoscopic video, where the channels have a well defined relationship to each other. Information about channels might be exposed through other APIs, such as [WEBAUDIO], but this specification provides no direct access to channels.

does it mean that the MediaStreamTrack is indeed a mere description of the data source, and to get the actual data we need to pass the MediaStreamTrack to the web audio API? Is this the lowest level I can get?

Does this answer your question? Get a stream of bytes from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()?

From what I understand, MediaStream is related to acquisition and redirection. You want to connect it to one of the (virtual) playback devices in order to capture that media.

Thanks, @Ouroborus, but I would like to avoid using the MediaRecorder.

@Ouroborus so the lowest level I can get to the data is to hook it up with one of the virtual devices?

As far as modern web browsers go, that's correct. You (and bad actors) don't get direct access to the media devices.

The Web Audio API has means to get you the raw PCM data directly from your MediaStream. Is it what you're after? With less browser support, you may also want to look at the Web Codecs API.
